# How to Animate a view onTouch event from one to another

Tags: android, animation, swipe

I'm working on the android app. In my app i want to move from first activity to second activity by swiping and by click on the tab button.

so please tell me how i can use the swipe in my app for moving to next activity when i swap from Right to left  and come back on first activity when i swap Left to right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GestureDector to get callbacks for left and right swipe motion.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

Answer (score 0):

let your activity implement OnGestureListener

and then override this method

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                    Intent i=new Intent(GroupScreen.this,TimeLineScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("clear", true);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left );





        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }

        return true;    
    }
```